# get page title then get category posts named the same as the title

Tags: php, wordpress

So, basically,
i created a slideshow.php template in order to query slider type of posts.

What i'm now trying to do is i need to create a page and the slideshow will show me the posts which are included in the category name the same as the post page name.

So if i have a Page named "post" the category name should be named "post"

I tried this:

```
echo $title=wp_title();
```

Here i get the page title Outside the loop.

My query is like this:

```
   query_posts(array('post_type'=>'slider',
                      'posts_per_page'=>'20',
'category_name' => '$title'
                      ));
```

But this isn't working.

Comment: And if you remove the single quotes from around `'$title'` what happens?

Comment: I feel so embarrased, i've been trying hard for ahmm 3 hours :/
Please add this ass an answer so i can accept it, thank you very much :)

Comment: Don't worry about it, sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from around your `$title` variable like so:

```
query_posts(array('post_type'=>'slider',
                  'posts_per_page'=>'20',
                  'category_name' => $title
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Curious, why would you want something like above? Why not just link to an ordinary category page?

You could then just create either a general template which does the same, but without you tempting with custom query, or you could do it with category templates for certain categories.

So, just wondering why you necessary want a page to do the job :)

Comment: i have created a template.. of slideshow type.. that's why i need to do it this way, or at least, this is the way i know how to do it.. :)

I create slides, then i divide them into pages...